# Object reference not set to an instance of an object 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

Here is my problem:

I cant display all the records from the database. 
there is an error that prompts 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I really don't know how will i fix this.

this is the error..

```
strProjectID = Request.QueryString["ProjectID"].ToString();
```

and here is the code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        strProjectID = Request.QueryString["ProjectID"].ToString();
        if (JQGrid1.AjaxCallBackMode != AjaxCallBackMode.None)            
        {               
            // save the last grid state in session - to be used for exporting                
            Session["gridFilterPageState"] = JQGrid1.GetState();            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's no `ProjectID` query string parameter passed to the request you are calling .ToString on a null instance. So make sure that you are passing this query string parameter when invoking the page: `/WebFormName.aspx?ProjectID=123`.

Comment: strProjectID = Request.QueryString["ProjectID"].ToString(null);

Comment: No, not like this. When calling this webform you need to pass the ProjectID query string parameter in the request. Like this: `/WebFormName.aspx?ProjectID=123`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when your specified parameter is not passed in given url...Be ensure that the parameter specified must be passed through url...
You can check whether request contains given parameter in following way :

```
if(Request.QueryString["ProjectID"] !=null)
{
   strProjectID = Request.QueryString["ProjectID"].ToString();
}
```

If you really want to have no check and no error at all, you can do like this:

```
 strProjectID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["ProjectID"]);
```

It'll returns `empty string` if `Querystring` does not contain `ProjectID`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this below piece of code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(Request.QueryString["ProjectID"] != null)
    {
       strProjectID = Request.QueryString["ProjectID"].ToString();
    }

    if (JQGrid1.AjaxCallBackMode != AjaxCallBackMode.None)            
    {               
        // save the last grid state in session - to be used for exporting                
        Session["gridFilterPageState"] = JQGrid1.GetState();            
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** The problem is that *ProjectID* may not be existing in the QueryString. So in order to be on the safe side, a null check is good to have.